# 'tns' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, nativescript

I have problems running tsn command, previously I installed and followed all nativescript instalation steps but tns is not running.
into the first picture basically, it says i can use tns now but not.
into the second picture tns does work.
Is very weird because tns worked 2 days ago, tns doctor, but today is not working.

[CHECK PICTUARE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjtva.png)

[CHECK PICTURE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgWsC.png)

Comment: Did you check your environment variable, is the modules path listed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous answer I had to check that again, I did that before but for any reason was removed, so.
Just if anyone else needs it and remember it later. go to:

1. Control Panel
2. System
3. Advance system settings
4. Environment Variables

   4.1. Into System Variables click on New:
   4.2. Variable name: PATH
   4.3. Variable value: c:\Users\'username'\AppData\Roaming\npm

I have not idea the difference between User variables for 'User' and System variables. I would like to understand more about it.

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbMMd.png)